# Contravariance (interface Function)

Tags: java

public  Function<V, U> compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before)

Can someone explain the way "? super T" works, I understand that super let us add an object in case of collections, but how does it work in this interface, why we need super in this interface to make method compose more flexible?

I would like to understand deeper wildcards, contravariance in java make a big problem for me.